# Is the User-Agent line in robots.txt an exact match or a substring match?

Tags: web-crawler, user-agent, robots.txt

When a crawler reads the User-Agent line of a robots.txt file, does it attempt to match it exactly to its own User-Agent or does it attempt to match it as a substring of its User-Agent?

Everything I have read does not explicitly answer this question. According to [another StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4676099/990642) it is an exact match.

However, the [RFC draft](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) makes me believe that it is a substring match. For example, `User-Agent: Google` will match "Googlebot" and "Googlebot-News". Here is the relevant quotation from the RFC:

> The robot must obey the first record in `/robots.txt` that contains a User-Agent line whose value contains the name token of the robot as a substring.

Additionally, in the "Order of precedence for user-agents" section of [Googlebot's documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) it explains that the user agent for Google Images "`Googlebot-Image/1.0`" match for `User-Agent: googlebot`.

I would appreciate any clarity here, and the answer may be more complicated than my question. For example, Eugene Kalinin's robots module for node mentions splitting the User-Agent to get the "name token" on [line 29](https://github.com/ekalinin/robots.js/blob/master/lib/entry.js) and matching against that. If this is true, then [Googlebot's User-Agent](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) "`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)`" will not match `User-Agent: Googlebot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [original robots.txt specification (from 1994)](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html), it says:

> **User-agent**
>
> […]
>
> The robot should be liberal in interpreting this field. A case insensitive substring match of the name without version information is recommended.
>
> […]

If and which bots/parsers comply with this is another question and can’t be answered in general.

Comment: This was a tough decision. I really liked plasticinsect's answer, but I think this is the most "correct". It sounds like crawlers should read robots.txt User-Agent lines as a case insensitive substring match, but each apply their own rules as plasticinsect says.

Answer (score 3):

Every robot does this a little differently. There is really no single reliable way to map the user-agent in robots.txt to the user-agent sent in the request headers. The safest thing to do is to treat them as two separate, arbitrary strings. <strike>The only 100% reliable way to find the robots.txt user-agent is to read the official documentation for the given robot.</strike>

**Edit:**

Your best bet is generally to read the official documentation for the given robot, but even this is not 100% accurate. As Michael Marr points out, Google has a robots.txt testing tool that can be used to verify which UA will work with a given robot. This tool reveals that their documentation is inaccurate. Specifically, the page https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/ claims that their media partner bots respond to the 'Googlebot' UA, but the tool shows that they don't.

Comment: "The only 100% reliable way to find the robots.txt user-agent is to read the official documentation for the given robot." <-- This. 

RE: Google, you can go to webmaster tools and crawl > blocked URLs to test various user agents and paths to see how Google specifically treats user agent strings. I did this and saw that "User-Agent: Google" matched nothing (according to the tool), and, as you referenced, Googlebot matched their regular bot, image bot, and mobile bot - but, it did NOT match their ad and media partner bots. At least for Google's implementation, the UA is not regex, but keyword.

Comment: @Michael Marr - Yes, you have a point. I tried your experiment and got the same result. The worst part is that this actually contradicts the official documentation. Apparently the docs are out-of-date. I have edited my answer.